# Custom Form disappears when switching pages in outlook appointment inspector

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I'm banging my head on this for the last 3 days:

I'm using vs 2013 to develop an Add-in to Outlook 2010 using Add-in Express.
I have created a custom form (inherited from Outlook.OL.ADXOlForm) and configured it in ADXOlFormsManager to be shown at the TopSubPane of an appointment inspector.

The problem starts when switching between pages of the inspector. At the beginning, when the inspector is shown in the first time, the 'Activity' page is shown and I can see the form exactly where it should be. When switching to 'Scheduling Assistant' page, the form exists at the right position, but when I switch back to the 'Activity' page, the form disappears. When switching back to 'Scheduling Assistant' page, the custom form is shown.

I would like the form to be shown at the TopSubPane of the inspector no matter of the current page that is shown in the inspector. What Am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend asking Add-in Express specific questions on [their forums](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/list.php?FID=5) instead. Nobody except core developers can answer your question - it can be a bug or feature. They simply may not support such scenario. Or you just use an old version of the framework. Too many answers are possible. But to get the definitive answer you need to contact them.

Did you have a chance to try using [Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead? Do they work correctly in that case?

Comment: Thank you for the respond. I will look into Forms Regions. Maybe that's the way. Thanks a lot